# Why was "Non-stop" retitled "Starship"?

Tags: title-explanation, non-stop-novel

I read this book a while ago, and there was one thing I remembered strongly about it: there was a plot twist where we learn that everyone is on a generation ship.

However, when I found the book again and saw its title I realized that maybe this shouldn't have been such a surprise:

[image: Cover of "Starship" with a picture of a starship]

The book was originally published under the less-spoilerly title [Non-stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Stop_(novel)). Apparently the title "Starship" is a US thing. But why was the title changed at all?

Comment: Presumably so it sounded like a science fiction book.

Comment: According to Currey, the US 1st edition was "somewhat abridged"; https://www.lwcurrey.com/pages/books/146616/brian-aldiss/starship It could be that the US editor retitled it because it's a substantially different work and wanted to distinguish them.

Comment: I've contacted his agency (by email) as well as a couple of members of his family (via twitter). Hopefully they can shed some light.

Answer (score 2):

I [contacted the author's Literary Estate](https://twitter.com/brianaldiss/status/1166086909095010305) to see if they had any info on the subject. The were kind enough to pointed me toward a note in [his autobiography](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2064990.Bury_My_Heart_At_W_H_Smith_s) which indicates that, in the author's opinion at least, the goal of his overseas publisher was to "simplify" the title and text for a younger US audience.

He was deeply upset about this and evidently voiced his concerns to them. Eventually future editions had the unedited text and original title, although the *'Starship'* edition also remained in print for decades.

> The contract duly arrived. A one-sheet job, brutally simple. I signed
> as instructed. I knew only Faber’s honest contracts, Ted knew no more
> than I. It was a contract with no release clause. As long as Criterion
> kept their edition in print, so long would S. G. Phillips take fifty
> per cent from any subsidiary sale, such as paperback or film rights.
>
> When eventually some copies of the Criterion edition filtered through,
> my disappointment was great. **The text had been altered, simplified.
> The title had been changed to Starship, which gave away the first
> major surprise of the novel, the binding appeared to be [a kind of
> sacking](https://historical.ha.com/itm/books/science-fiction-and-fantasy/brian-aldiss-starship-criterion-1959-first-edition-first-printing-toning-and-minor-rubbing-to/a/201243-90009.s), and the whole presentation was aimed at a juvenile or
> semi-juvenile market.** As I write, the Criterion edition is officially
> still in print. For obvious reasons, I cannot comment on that.
>
> <sub><sup>[Bury My Heart At W.H.Smith's](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2064990.Bury_My_Heart_At_W_H_Smith_s)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the publisher simply preferred a different title.

There are many examples of the same story being published under different titles. Poul Anderson's "The makeshift Rocket" appeared in *Astounding* as "A Bicycle Built For Brew", "The Enemy Stars" as "We Have Fed Our Sea", and "Planet of No Return" as "Question and Answer", probably because John W Campbell thought the original titles too bland. Also his "After Doomsday" had appeared in *Galaxy* as "The Day After Doomsday".

Similarly, Hal Clement's "Needle" has also been published as "From Outer Space" and Aldiss' own "Bow Down To Nul" first appeared in *New Worlds* as "X For Exploitation".
n
Short stories commonly get the same treatment. Thus Arthur C Clarke's "Royal Prerogative" has also appeared as "Refugee" or just as "?". In short, it's just an irritating habit that publishers (and magazine editors) seem to have.

Comment: This seems like guesswork. Can you offer any evidence that this was the *specific* reason this work was retitled? As opposed to, say, not wanting to conflict with another work of the same name or because the author wanted to distinguish between different versions

Comment: What sort of evidence have you in mind? Unless either the author or the publisher has gone on record about it, we are never likely to know for certain. I agree my answer is a surmise, but I suspect that an educated guess is about all that will ever be possible on this one.

Comment: Yes, both of those things would be excellent evidence.

Comment: I know that Aldiss hated the US title (he said so at a convention I attended) because it gave away the mystery. So he probably wasn't consulted in the matter.

Comment: Writers also sometimes rename their stories, often when they appear in collections rather than the orginal magazine publication, where the editor didn't like the writer's name. For instance, Joe Haldeman's "Summer's Lease" was renamed as "Truth to Tell", and Le Guin's "Vaster than Empires" originally appeared under a different title (which I can't offhand recall).